# Loading numpy arrays into Fortran quickly

Tags: python, fortran, storage, loading

I am currently working on a Fortran program, which requires a large data file as input. This data file is created using Python, and I am currently saving it in a human readable format using the `np.savetxt()` function.

However, the size of this file is very large (at least 1.5GB of disk space) and so reading in the file takes a long time. I think it might be easier to save the array of data in a binary format using `np.save` (or maybe pickle it?), however I have no idea how I would read this file into my Fortran program - is there a simple way to do this?

I realise that an alternative solution to this would be to entirely cut Python out of the picture and create the data array in Fortran, however as I am close to a complete beginner in Fortran I am trying to minimise the amount of things I need it for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on your data structures, but if it is just one or a few arrays you don't need any external libraries (I am not impressed with all the hassle of NetCDF).

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros([10,10], order="F")
a.tofile("a.bin")
```

and

```
  use iso_fortran_env
  real(real64) :: a(10,10)

  open(newunit=iu,file="a.bin",access="stream",status="old",action="read")
  read(iu) a
  close(iu)
end
```

and that's all.

Comment: Shouldn't you dump transpose of an array `a`, i.e.`a.T.tofile("a.bin")`?

Comment: Why do you think so? Definitely not. Notice the F order.

Comment: Ha, you're right. I loaded data using `pandas.read_csv` and had to transpose it before dumping. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In my day to day work, I run a very large simulation switching between fortran and python for computation and visualization purposes. I would suggest using the netcdf libraries in both of them, netcdf is an excellent format for transferring between the two systems and keeps the file size in check. Some good links are provided below

Python : http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/

Fortran : http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/examples/programs/